# Drupal URL Redirection

Tags: apache, url, drupal, redirect

The homepage of our website - http://urn1350.net/, we would like to change to http://urn1350.net/elections to be the homepage. What options do I have for URL redirection in the backend on a drupal and apache server

Answer (score 4):

If you actually want /elections to *be* the front page and not just redirect, go to /admin/config/system/site-information and you can change the default front page from "front" (or whatever you have now). I'd suggest trying this in a dev/QA environment first!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an "elections" folder in the http root and move the Drupal site to the folder.
2. Change the htaccess to rewrite the urls to the folder

.htacces

```
# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
# uncomment the following line:
RewriteBase /elections
```